# Is every cell in flowdirection draining towards an outlet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, hydrology

I have created a Flowdirection map in a defined catchment.

I want to find out if every cell in my map is flowing towards the creek/outlet.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I have created the catchment using watershed.

Comment: It's kinda the definition of a catchment - the area inside it flows towards the drainage point of said catchment. If it didn't, it would be in another catchment area. (If this is not what you are asking, please update your question and clarify.)

Comment: No, your surface model may contain sinks. If you have sinks, the cells flowing into those sinks will not have an outlet. There is a fill sinks pre-processing tool in the ArcToolbox.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest that you run the [WaterShed Tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Watershed/009z00000059000000/) on the data.

It will give a raster which indicates each watershed in that area, and then you can see whether each cell in your study area drains in the same creek or Sink.